# STFT uniform continuity

Tags: fourier-transform, uniform-continuity

I want to show that short-time Fourier transform of $f \in L^2$ w.r.t $g \in L^2$
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{V}_{g} f (x, \omega) = \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}^{} f(t) \overline{g(t-x)} e^{-2 \pi i t \omega} dt = \langle f, M_{\omega} T_x \, g \rangle
\end{align*}
(where $M_{\omega}$ is modulation and $T_x$ translation) is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R} ^2$. My attempt:
\begin{align*}
\lvert \mathcal{V}_{g} f (x, \omega) - \mathcal{V}_{g} f (x', \omega ')\rvert & = \lvert \langle f, M_{\omega} T_x g -  M_{\omega '} T_{x'} g \rangle  \rvert \\  & \leq \lVert f \rVert _2 \, \lVert M_{\omega } T_{x} g - M_{\omega '} T_{x'} g \rVert _2
\end{align*}
and I want to use
\begin{align*}
\lVert T_x h - h \rVert _2 \rightarrow 0 \; \; \; \text{as} \; \; \; \;  x \rightarrow 0
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\lVert M_{\omega } h - h \rVert _2 \rightarrow 0 \; \; \; \text{as} \; \; \; \;  \omega \rightarrow 0
\end{align*}
so I tried estimating
\begin{align*}
\lVert M_{\omega } T_{x} g - M_{\omega '} T_{x'} g \rVert _2 & \leq \lVert M_{\omega } T_{x} g - M_{\omega '} T_{x} g \rVert _2 + \lVert M_{\omega '} T_{x} g - M_{\omega '} T_{x'} g \rVert _2 \\ & = \lVert M_{\omega } T_{x} g - M_{\omega '} T_{x} g \rVert _2 + \lVert T_{x-x'} g - g \rVert _2
\end{align*}
and now I am struggling to estimate first term in the last line ($\lVert M_{\omega } T_{x} g - M_{\omega '} T_{x} g \rVert _2$) in such a way that I can apply the limits above. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I think that using the density of compactly supported continuous functions in $L_2$ might be useful.